# Is possible to lower power consumption at new Kernel 3.2?

Tags: linux, laptop, power-management, kernel

I'm currently using Kernel 3.2, but i'm don't like it's high power consumption. Is there any way to lower it. I'm currently using Arch. But i'm not afraid of gentoo where almost everything gets compiled at my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install a whole new distribution, you can just install your own [kernel](http://www.kernel.org/) under arch, with the power management [patch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/11/10/467) destined for kernel 3.3 applied.

The arch default kernel is 3.1, so presumably you are using an AUR kernel?  I don't see one there for 3.2 so if you have compiled your own already, then applying the patch should be straightforward.